# How does lapply really work - lapply dcast?

Tags: r, reshape, lapply

Obviously I still do not understand fully how lapply really works. Sure, it applies a function over list elements and returns a list. Yet when using it with custom functions I am not so sure how to use it efficiently. I want to use it in a custom function that uses dcast for example.

First let's get an example dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame(idx=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3)),
              cat=rep(1:3,3),var1=rnorm(9,0,1)
 )



df2 <- data.frame(idx=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4),rep("c",4)),
              cat2=rep(1:4,3),var1=rnorm(12,0,1)
              )

mylist <- list(cat=df1,cat2=df2)


library(reshape2)

### result that I want to get just for one data.frame
dcast(df1,idx~cat,value_var="var1")
```

But I can't get this to go with lapply, I tried:

```
lapply(mylist,function(x) substitute(dcast(x,idx~x,value_var="var1")))
## returns
$cat
dcast(X[[2L]], idx ~ X[[2L]], value_var = "var1")
```

Obviously X[[2L]] would not work when evaluating the expression. Further I tried

```
lapply(names(mylist), function(x) dcast(mylist[[x]],idx~x,value_var="var1" ))
```

which was working in some similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002227/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-data-frame-within-a-list), but caused an error here. Should I use with here?

EDIT: 
I am surprised that Joshua's answers is exactly what I want. I was on that trail before but dismissed it early when I tried:

```
 test <- function(x){
 myformula <- as.formula(paste("idx~",x,sep=""))
 myformula
 }

 test(df2) 
 ## returns
 ## > idx ~ c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
 ## > <environment: 0x104f0a4d8>
```

Obviously too early, but can you explain what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, `x` is an object passed to your function.  In the second example, it's a character string.  In both cases, it's not a symbol that represents a variable in the `data` passed to `dcast`.

You need to construct your formula using the name of the list element, so something like this:

```
# define the function
myfunc <- function(varname) {
  # 'varname' is a character string naming the column to use
  myformula <- as.formula(paste("idx~",varname,sep=""))
  dcast(mylist[[varname]], myformula, value_var="var1")
}
# loop over list elements, by name
lapply(names(mylist), myfunc)
```

Comment: Also, I believe it's `value.var` not `value_var`.

Comment: @joran: "value_var name of column which stores values" quoted from the ?dcast. maybe yours works as well, but my single example without lapply does work.

Comment: @ran2 Perhaps we're using different versions. For me, it runs but issues a warning stating that since you haven't passed a value in for `value.var` it's using `var1` by default.

Comment: Thanx, this is exactly what I want, but after checking what's actually pasted in myformula, I really don't understand why it works. Is there a way to do it the substitute way, i.e. gettin the data.frame's / column's name to the formula and then eval it?

Comment: @ran2: it works because you named the `mylist` elements with the name of the column in data.frame you wanted to use.  You could also grep for the `cat*` column and use that to construct `myformula` (in which case you could loop over `mylist` directly, instead of `names(mylist)`), but I'm not sure of your actual problem's requirements.

Comment: @Joshua: I did that naming thing on purpose. In fact I like your solution using as.formula which fits my needs just perfectly. Intuitively I would have looked to create something with substitute to eval. However, thanks for helping out where my intuition could not.